# Visual Studio Code Live Share

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm currently working on a robotics project and am collectively working on code through the Live Share extension in Microsoft Visual Studio Code. However, when I am not working, my partners cannot. Is there any way to share ownership of our files in Visual Studio Code or put the files somewhere to do the same?

Thanks!

Comment: You can host code for free on GitHub, or BitBucket with a free account.

Comment: Live Share is intended for use with pair programming or troubleshooting/helping, not for co-working on the same project, you should start using a distributed version control system, such as [git](http://git-scm.com).